# How can I publish NUnit test results using Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, nunit, jenkins-pipeline

Trying to use the nifty Jenkins Pipeline, I had problems finding out how to publish NUnit test results.

I am able to run the tests by specifying the following command in the pipeline script:

```
stage 'Test'
    bat '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NUnit 2.6.4\\bin\\nunit-console-x86.exe" "ProjectName\\bin\\Release\\UnitTests.net.dll"'
```

But how to make Jenkins "publish" the test results is not obvious. The Snippet Generator only suggests junit, and that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I used nunit plugin version 0.21 and was able to publish results using

```
stage("PublishTestReport"){
     nunit testResultsPattern: 'TestResult.xml'
     }
```

(TestResult.xml is at the root of jenkins workspace in this above example)

Comment: It seems like the issue has been resolved at this time.

Comment: @OlaEldøy can you accept this answer? It helps to see if a question has been answered.

Comment: I really wish they'd just put this front and center on their [plugin page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nunit/) - thanks for adding this here!

Answer (score 14):

Investigating the NUnit plugin for Jenkins led me on to [this issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27618), where I found the solution:

```
step([$class: 'NUnitPublisher', testResultsPattern: 'TestResult.xml', debug: false, 
                 keepJUnitReports: true, skipJUnitArchiver:false, failIfNoResults: true])
```

Adding this to the pipeline script worked for me!

However, it seemed the following should also work (but at the present, apparently, it does not): Using the Snippet Generator, select this:

```
step: General Build Step
Publish NUnit test result report
```

This generates the following in the Pipeline script:

```
step <object of type hudson.plugins.nunit.NUnitPublisher>
```

This fails!